# Is there a way to restore the 'packages.config' file in a C# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

For whatever reason after pulling this solution off our TF server, all of the 'packages.config' files are missing that I believe are used for restoring Nuget packages when the projects are being built.

Is there any way to make VS restore these files automatically?

EDIT:

more of a follow-up question, since I can't make another, VS is fully disallowing me from adding references to one of the projects now.

I can't point it to the DLL's, I can't remove the reference and re-add them, installing/reinstalling the Nuget packages will not fix the references. Rebuilding, restarting VS, running as admin, etc. - nothing will make these references stop having the yellow triangle. Many of the things it is claiming it cannot find are built in.

[image]

Comment: Meaning that you've not added the packages.config to source control. There is no way to restore that file from nowhere!

Comment: Without packages.config VS can't group references into packages. I doubt that there is a way to do what you want.

Comment: Which is silly because it knows what packages it doesn't have due to missing references.

Comment: VS doesn't know anything about packages. It knows about assembly references. Packages.config is being processed by Nuget and appropriate targets file (using msbuild).